# Complex object validation with enterprise library validation block

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

Am using the enterprise library validation.

I have classes like below

```
 public class Customer
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "{1} is null")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "{1} is null")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

    }

  public class Order
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "{1} is null")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    }
```

When am using the order object and surname and first name are null validation should kick in ,but it does not.

What am i doing wrong?

Note: Am using it with WCF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should decorate your Customer property with the  `[ObjectValidator]` attribute. This will insure that the Validation Application will validate object graphs:

```
public class Order
{
    [ObjectValidator]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Tip: You should read the ValidationHOL.pdf (hands on lab) document that comes with the [Validation Application Block 4.1 Hands On Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2C34A9CB-17CF-4AEC-8DE6-EEACBBB74413&displaylang=en) (the PDF is part of the download). It will give you a lot of information about the VAB that will be hard to find out on your.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly declared your validation rules, however you didn't *validate* your customer (evaluate the rules). Validation with the enterprise library validation block works like this:

```
ValidationResults r = Validation.Validate<Customer>(myCustomer);
```

See the corresponding [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309320.aspx).

Comment: This is not practical, because it doesn't enable validation of object graphs.